# Menu doesn't expand

Tags: 7, navigation

I have a primary link created and set of links whose parent is the primary link.

I have enabled "Show as expanded" to all of them (tried with first primary also) but yet the sub-menus don't appear in the screen.

How do I resolve it?

I have went through Structure -> Menus -> Main Menu and list links.[image]

Then, I have clicked edit on the About Me link.

[image]

Comment: Not all themes have javascript dropdown menus, or show the children of parent menus. What theme are you using? Where are you displaying your menu? A block? the primary navigation bar? You may need to install a module such as https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish

Comment: I am using batik theme.  And i am displaying a primary navigation bar

Comment: Yep, bartik doesn't display children of parent menu items via the primary navigation bar.  Superfish is a good way to get started with that functionality

Comment: So I just need to install the module and enable it right?

Comment: You will need to follow the instructions on the module page.  You have to install the superfish javascript library in the sites/all/libraries folder, then enable the module that goes into the sites/all/modules folder.  Several blocks will be generated. goto admin/structure/blocks and configure one of them to use your primary menu, and then place the block in a region of your choice. You may want to disable the main menu default display, in admin/appearance/bartik by unchecking the Main Menu checkbox in the Toggle Display section. Good luck and keep asking questions!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with bartik theme then there is one tutorial at [Add drop down menu support to Bartik](https://www.drupal.org/node/1508652). However I have not tested it, but comments suggests that it works. It is as easy as adding some custom CSS to main menu in bartik theme.

My suggestion would be to use some other theme such as [skeletontheme](https://www.drupal.org/project/skeletontheme), which is responsive and have good support to your requirement. I have used this theme a lot for many projects.

Comment: I am going with normal html now.  I am fed up with drupal.  Things are so complicated here

Comment: Drupal is quite awesome!  Don't give up! Keep trying, and learn a few things, and i'm sure you can be successful.